# Kendo Scheduler hide weekends from agenda and month view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

If I have a task that takes more then a week (ex: Monday 20 jan - Monday 27 jan) then in the Kendo Scheduler, in month-view or in agenda-view, the task will appear in the weekend too (Saturday 25 Jan and Sunday 26 Jan).

**Q:** How can I hide the weekend days from a task?

```
    @(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<TasksModel>() 
       .Name("scheduler")
       .Editable(false)
       .Date(DateTime.Today)
       .Views(views => {
          views.MonthView(monthView => monthView.Selected(true));
          views.AgendaView();
       }) 
       .BindTo(Model.searchResults)
    )
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the only solution here as I see it would be to manipulate the datasource before you display it and split up tasks into weeks, with start and end date from monday to friday for that week.